# Accessing Readline's "application name" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, readline

Is there any way (supported or otherwise) to set Readline's `rl_readline_name` variable from Ruby's `Readline` module?  Or even to read it to find out the current value?

It seems to be only marginally documented and supported in the C library, with about the only mention being how to use the value in `.inputrc` to conditionalise settings.

Comment: is it just "Ruby"? https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_3/ext/readline/readline.c#L1934

Comment: Yes it is, although I had to insert an `$if Ruby/$endif` definition in `.inputrc` to verify it.  Meh.  It looks as though that cell isn't exposed through the Ruby bindings, but I haven't finished searching.  Thanks for the find!

Comment: maybe if you could explain what's your end goal is here, there might be other solutions.

Comment: First goal is to be able to set the application name so I can add application-specific customisations to `.inputrc`.  Second goal is to make the Ruby interface more closely resemble the underlying C interface.

Comment: it doesn't look like `rl_readline_name` is meant to be set by the end user ([example](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/bash-5.2/bashline.c#L462)), you could use `INPUTRC` env var to load a different .inputrc file. you could use `Reline` which is the default ruby implementation of readline now and patch this [part](https://github.com/ruby/reline/blob/v0.5.0.pre.1/lib/reline/config.rb#L239-L240) to maybe set application name from env.

Comment: I'm not trying to set it as an end user; I'm trying to set it as an application [developer].  My application is written in Ruby but it isn't the Ruby language.  What little documentation there is on `readline`'s support of application names doesn't seem to obviate this.  Another possibility would be the '`$if variable`' `.inputrc` construct, but again the docco is more than a little lacking on the whole "variable" concept.  If it does/could use envariables, that would be a workaround.  Else I think the answer to my question is basically, "Nope, you can't get there from here." :-(